# How close is Python to being able to wrap it in a workbook type skin?

Tags: python, wrapper, openaccess

With my luck this question will be closed too quickly.  I see a tremendous possibility for a python application that basically is like a workbook.  Imagine if you will that instead of writing code you select from a menu of choices.  For example, the File menu would have an open command that lets the user navigate to a file or directory of file or a webpage, even a list of web pages and specify those as the things that will be the base for the next actions.

Then you have a find menu.  The menu would allow easy access to the various parsing tools, regular expression and string tools so you can specify the thing you want to find within the files.

Another menu item could allow you to create queries to interact with database objects.

I could go on and on.  As the language becomes more higher level then these types of features become easier to implement.  There is a tremendous advantage to developing something like this.  How much time is spent reinventing the wheel for mundane tasks?  Programmers have functions that they have built to do many mundane tasks but what about democratizing the power offered by a tool like Python.

I have people in my office all of the time asking how to solve problems that seem intractable to them, but when I show them how with a few lines of code their problem is solvable except for the edge cases they become amazed.  I deflect their gratitude with the observation that it is not really that hard except for being able to construct the right google search to identify the right package or library to solve the problem.  There is nothing amazing about my ability to use lxml and sets to pull all bolded sections from a collection of say 12,000 documents and compare across time and across unique identifiers in the collection how those bolded sections have evolved/changed or converged.  The amazing piece is that someone wrote the libraries to do these things.

What is the advantage to the community for something like this.  Imagine if you would an interface that looks like a workbook but interacts with an app-store.  So if you want to pull something from html file you go to the app store and buy a plug-in that handles the work.  If the workbook is built robustly enough it could be licensed to a machine, the 'apps' would be tied to a particular workbook.

Just imagine the creativity that could be unleashed by users if they could get over the feeling that access to this power is difficult.  You guys may not see this but I see Python being so close to being able to port to something like a workbook framework.  Weren't the early spreadsheet programs nothing more than a frame around some Fortran libraries that had been ported to C?

Comments or is there such an application and I have not found it.

Comment: Its a cute idea, pity that this is not the place.

Comment: Maybe try the Python Ideas mail list: http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas.

Comment: This sounds like Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Python application that are based on generating code -- the most amazing one probably [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/), which focuses on spreadsheets (and hinges on IronPython). With that exception, however, interacting based on the UI paradigm you have in mind (pick one of this, one of that, etc) tends to be pretty limited in the gamut of choices it offers to let the user generate the exact application they need -- there's just **so** much more you can say by writing even a little script, than what you can say by point-and-grunt.

That being said, Python would surely be a great choice both to implement such an app and as the language to generate... if and when you have a UI sketch that looks like it can actually allow non-programmers to specify a large-enough spectrum of apps in a broad-enough domain!-). Spreadsheets have proven themselves in this sense, but I don't know of other niches or approaches that have actually done so -- do you?

Comment: Well I don't think anything else has developed enough to allow.  And further, while the P&G approach might be limiting now, I remember the amazement I felt when I first bought Lotus 1-2-3 but also thought of it as a toy as compared to a real thinking man's tool FORTRAN.  I bragged about my calculator.  Sure, I can do more with those few snippets of script but the learning curve is so steep and that extra stuff is unnecessary for what a lot of the users I am imaging would want.

Comment: @Burch, so mock out a user interface that covers what you're "imagining" and fully lets the user specify one user-desired app within a huge range -- implementing it in terms of code generation will then be very simply (especially though not exclusively in Python). I just don't have the UI/UX nous to conceive of it, just like I didn't invent spreadsheets either;-).

Answer (score 1):

Your idea kinda reminded me of something I stumbled across months ago: http://www.ailab.si/orange/

Answer (score 0):

Is your concept very similar to Microsoft Access? Generally programmers tend not to write such programs because they produce such horrible code that the authors themselves would never want to use their program.